# Windows Terminal won't open in current directory

Tags: windows-10, windows-terminal

I want to open Windows Terminal in the current folder when I write wt in the address bar. I am running Windows 10 22H2 19045.2604.

I've tried setting the starting directory to null and . in settings.json, I've tried removing the starting directory line altogether, re-installing Windows Terminal but none of these options work. I am currently using Powershell 7.3.2.

This is settings.json currently:

```json
{
    "defaults": 
    {
        "elevate": true
    },
    "list": 
    [
        {
            "guid": "{574e775e-4f2a-5b96-ac1e-a2962a402336}",
            "hidden": false,
            "name": "PowerShell",
            "source": "Windows.Terminal.PowershellCore"
        }
    ]
},
```

[Disabling registry virtualization did not fix the issue.](https://superuser.com/questions/21786/how-to-disable-folder-and-registry-virtualisation-in-vista/21788#21788)

Running `wt -d .` from the address bar also does not work.

Also worth noting that shift+right clicking and then pressing open in Terminal does work but not from the address bar.

Comment: does this work? `wt -d .` (note the space and the period)

Comment: nope still opens system32

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  The reason why it is opening in `System32` is because WT is set to always run as Administrator (from `"elevate": true`).  If you change this to false, then `wt -d .` should open to the current directory.

Comment: Why does changing the terminal to always run as administrator cause it to open from System32 every time? I don't get the issue when I am right clicking.

Comment: @LordLance I'm not sure *why* yet.  But I can reproduce the issue if I set WT to always open as Administrator as well.  For that reason, I was asking for it to be re-eopened so that it can entertain potential answers.